# How to write in txt file and find common words in message history from slack in Python?

Tags: python, counter, slack-api

Please help me to write in txt file slack message history and find common words in it.
In my code example I have to problems:
1) Only first message is written in the file.
2) Counter works for each message seperately not for all message history.

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
from collections import Counter
import re

sc = SlackClient('token')
channel = "C200SFJNR"

def history():
        history_call = sc.api_call("channels.history", channel=channel, count=1000)
        if history_call.get('ok'):
                return history_call['messages']
        return None

history = history()
for c in history:
        text=(c['text'])
        with open("out.txt", 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)
        common = Counter(words).most_common(10)
        print(common)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question is easily answered without a knowledge of slackclient. Your reference to Counter is in a loop. Hence, each time you reference it a new instance of it is created and the old one is lost. What you want is to create an instance of Counter before you enter the loop, add items to it within the loop and then after you exit the loop make the call on most_common to obtain that information.